# Clothing preference and Skin type of race which can absorb heat energy via skin?

Tags: creature-design, fantasy-races, low-fantasy, clothing

My alien race is able to absorb energy via the skin, like plants using sunlight for photosynthesis.
The race eats a lot of food, like humans, But they need this absorbed energy for their proper inner functionality. They are cold-blooded, and they do not have any internal mechanism to keep their body temperature. They are depending on this absorbed heat for this. But they cant absorb direct sunlight. Some elements in this world have the power to absorb and emit heat from sunlight in a different form -and this race can absorb only that.
The temperature on the planet is a bit lower - an average of 20°C.

Since they are absorbing the energy via the skin, it makes sense to wear fewer clothes and expose more skin - or is it the other way around - like wearing many layers of dress to make them keep warm?
Also how will be their skin - I saw plants in cool places that have pointed and hard leaves, so will their skin need to be like that - very hard ? or pale skin like people who live in cold places?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

> Some elements in this world have the power to absorb and emit heat
> from sunlight in a different form.

Those people can makes clothes in which those elements are studded. The outer part (part of elements outside the clothes) receives sunlight and the inner part (part of elements inside the clothes) emits heat which is absorbed by the body.

**Black bodies with non-reflecting surface**

Black bodies absorb heat more. So their skin could be black with non-reflecting surface so that it absorbs maximum heat.

Answer (score 1):

**The Cloaca**

[image]

The naughty bits of a lizard are kept safely inside the cloaca. The cloaca being of course the single opening where the waste goes out and the sex goes in. See Dinosaur Comics:

[image]

When they are warming up for the day your lizard people wear *nothing at all*:

[image]

They like to find a nice hot rock and lie with their belly next to it. This speeds the warm up part of the day.

Once the lizard people are warm they put on heavy clothes to lock in the heat. [See this answer for details](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/196827/14322).